# Is it possible to control the size of a lookup dialog? - CRM 2011 online

Tags: dynamics-crm-2011, dynamics-crm, crm, dynamics-crm-online

Is there any way to alter the default display size of a lookup dialog? Users are constantly having to re-size. Probably can't implement an unsupported method but would like to know about either. I've looked around but haven't found anything of use for online scenario.

Answer (score 1):

How about something like that:

http://lakshmanindian.wordpress.com/2012/10/02/open-crm-2011-lookup-window-in-a-custom-html-page/

Comment: Very interesting! Will try it out in next few days and let you know how I get on...